# any python library that handles large dictionary?

Tags: python, caching

My python scripts are getting killed as they are running to several GB of RAM usage. I found that this is because of my large size dictionary being created.

I want to write a library that will handle such large dictioary by caching to disk. I will specify the maximum RAM usage and it will cache to disk and run.

Is there any python library that already exists that does this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is only about dicts, have a look at [DiskDict](https://github.com/ddofborg/diskdict).

Comment: Thanks. I will test this. This is exactly what I need !